# How to match an inline JavaScript event with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

Does anyone know a method to identify an inline JavaScript event-handler with Nokogiri or something else?

I'd like to extract the `onload="alert('Page is loaded');"` from this tag:

```
<body onload="alert('Page is loaded');">
</body>
```

I need a generic method which can identify all JavaScript event handlers.

---

**Edit :**

I need to prevent users from recording inline JavaScript event-handler within a wysiwyg (tinyMCE) form.

For now, I do that with gsub :

```
self.description.gsub(/onafterprint/i, '****')       
self.description.gsub(/onbeforeprint/i, '****')       
self.description.gsub(/onbeforeunload/i, '****')
...
```

This is not really smart...
I was wondering if it would be possible with Nokogiri? Would it more usefull and faster ?

I allready know how to find all my doc's attribute with Nokogiri (maybe not the best method)

```
html_doc.xpath('//@*').each do |e|
    puts e.name
    # I need something like that :
    e.remove if e.javascript_event_handler?
end
```

My main Question is how to match every existing inline JavaScript event-handler.
It don't seems that a generic method exists. Am I wrong ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried? Please show your attempts solving the problem. As is, it looks like you want us to write it for you. CSS and XPath make it easy to locate the event-handler parameters in tags, so a little research of those should help solve your problem. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]".

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help you:

```
//body[contains(@onload,'alert')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Inline event handlers starts with "on" prefix (exclude animations, i think),
so you can write something as:

```
html_doc.xpath('//@*').each do |e|
  e.remove if e.name.start_with? "on"
end
```